# Can I get the ID of an anchor tag if the inner text of two items in a table match my criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Table]

I have a table (pictured) with ID "PTSRCHRESULTS" and the rows are all anchors/links. I need the ID of any element (doesn't matter which) on the row that contains "Undergrad" and "1". This is actually to use in Power Automate Desktop but I can run JavaScript to get the ID to click the element I need.

So in this example if I can get the specific ID for the 6th row in the table. I know that I can target a single element for example:

```
var element = $( "a:contains('Undergrad')" );
```

But I don't know how to chain those together for two items. Thanks!

Added an edited sample of the table code for reference:

```
<table id="PTSRCHRESULTS" class="PSSRCHRESULTSWBO" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpading="1" summary="Student Program/Plan Search Results. Row 1-7 of 7">
<tbody>
    <th scope="row" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a id="SEARCH_RESULT1" name="RESULT1$0" aria-describedby="app_label PSSRCHSUBTITLE PSSRCHINSTRUCTIONS" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow0');" tabindex="54" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">00013XXXX</a></th>
    <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT2$0" id="RESULT2$0" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow0');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">Postgrad</a></td>
    <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT3$0" id="RESULT3$0" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow0');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">1</a></td>
    <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT4$0" id="RESULT4$0" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow0');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">MMedSonog</a></td>
    <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT5$0" id="RESULT5$0" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow0');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">TestPlace</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <th scope="row" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT1$1" id="RESULT1$1" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow1');" tabindex="55" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">00013403U</a></th>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT2$1" id="RESULT2$1" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow1');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">Postgrad</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT3$1" id="RESULT3$1" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow1');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">0</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT4$1" id="RESULT4$1" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow1');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">GDMedRad</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT5$1" id="RESULT5$1" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow1');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">TestPlace</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <th scope="row" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT1$2" id="RESULT1$2" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow2');" tabindex="56" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">00013403U</a></th>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT2$2" id="RESULT2$2" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow2');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">Undergrad</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT3$2" id="RESULT3$2" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow2');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">4</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT4$2" id="RESULT4$2" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow2');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">BMedRadSc</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT5$2" id="RESULT5$2" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow2');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">TestPlace</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <th scope="row" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT1$3" id="RESULT1$3" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow3');" tabindex="57" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">00013403U</a></th>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT2$3" id="RESULT2$3" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow3');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">Undergrad</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT3$3" id="RESULT3$3" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow3');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">3</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT4$3" id="RESULT4$3" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow3');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">BMedRadSc</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT5$3" id="RESULT5$3" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow3');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">TestPlace</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <th scope="row" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT1$4" id="RESULT1$4" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow4');" tabindex="58" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">00013403U</a></th>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT2$4" id="RESULT2$4" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow4');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">Undergrad</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT3$4" id="RESULT3$4" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow4');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">2</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT4$4" id="RESULT4$4" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow4');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">BMidwifery</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW"><a name="RESULT5$4" id="RESULT5$4" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow4');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW">TestPlace</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
        <th scope="row" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT1$5" id="RESULT1$5" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow5');" tabindex="59" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">00013403U</a></th>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT2$5" id="RESULT2$5" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow5');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">Undergrad</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT3$5" id="RESULT3$5" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow5');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">1</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT4$5" id="RESULT4$5" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow5');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">BCommerce</a></td>
        <td class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW"><a name="RESULT5$5" id="RESULT5$5" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICRow5');" class="PSSRCHRESULTSEVENROW">TestPlace</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you share your table as code not image ?

Comment: @SelVazi have added a sample for reference, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate thru each row and then look at the column values to get the content of both columns.  As each row's first column is th and not td, following code is applicable.

```
        $('table > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 
           console.log(index);
           console.log(tr);
           console.log($('td:eq(0)',this).text());
           console.log($('td:eq(1)',this).text());
           if($('td:eq(0)',this).text()=="Undergrad" && $('td:eq(1)',this).text()=="1") {
               console.log("I FOUND IT!!");
           }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to find a solution using your answer.